# JavaScript "AH01215: (8)Exec format error" "End of script output before headers" on Apache

Tags: javascript, apache

Finally time to apply JavaScript to a particular web site, so I wrote some code that works fine in a test sub-directory, but when I went to deploy this to the web site I ran into problem(s). The problem(s) appears to be unique to when I'm trying to use a script file that's not in the directory or a sub-directory to where the page that's calling it is located. And this would be a show-stopper because the new functionality is needed site wide and the directory structure dynamically changes based on other mechanisms we don't need to get into here; the ability to call a top-level script is vital.

So, I stripped it all down to two lines of very simple JavaScript to help illuminate the issues; when it is contained in a file in the directory where the calling html resides, it works, or a subdirectory from there, OR if I refer to it in the same directory via a link to another location, that's fine too. But if I try and refer to the script file in any other way, it fails with:

> [Thu Dec 08 12:08:26.643037 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 27403] [client
>   xx.xx.xx.xx:46247] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of
>   '/usr/www/http/js/test.js' failed, referer:
>   http://example.com/test/jstest.html [Thu Dec 08 12:08:26.643548 2016]
>   [cgi:error] [pid 27403] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:46247] End of script
>   output before headers: test.js, referer:
>   http://example.com/test/jstest.html

Here, of course, xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP of the server, "example.com" is the domain in question, and the path '/usr/www/http' is the top level directory Apache serves this domain's web site from.

I've read a lot of materials on this and I know the Apache configuration files matter... I've tried setting a ScriptAlias and have a few questions about it I can't seem to find clarity on:

1. Just how are scripts in the "ScriptAlias" directory refered to in the HTML code - start with
   a slash? Is there some special character to say "top of site?" And;
2. Is there only one unique ScriptAlias directory permitted for the
   whole site, or can one have multiple directories that are searched -
   and if so, how do you specify them, multiple definitions of ScriptAlias, comma
   separated list, etc? And;
3. Can we set one per VirtualHost? And do we do this by putting a
   ScriptAlias inside the Virtual Host definition?

To make testing a little easier I made multiple instances of almost the same code in files of the same name in various directories, and altered the contents slightly so I could easily determine which location had taken effect with what kind of a call, all the while looking at the Apache logs. Here's an example from one of these files:

```
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h2');
myHeading.textContent = 'website top level js dir';
```

Obviously, I was changing the textContent to match what the location was.

In the HTML, any reference like any of these worked so long as the calling page was either in the same directory as test.js or in a parent directory or if there was a link to test.js that was either in the same directory or a subdirectory:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/test/js/test.js"></script>
```

In the HTML, any reference like these always failed no matter what I tried so long as the calling html was not in the same directory or a parent directory:

```
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>
<script src="/usr/WWW/http/js/test.js></script>
<script src="http://example.com/test/js/test.js"></script>
```

The directories and files involved are all owned by my personal UID and GID (as they always have been), and their permissions are all 755.

There's a global ScriptAlias defined as (also tried variations on this):

```
ScriptAlias /js/ "/usr/www/js/"
```

There's another ScriptAlias entry in the Virtual Host definition - no idea if it does anything!

OK, I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simply put:

Apache presumes that all content coming from any directory that's identified in any `ScriptAlias` directive is intended for the Server to execute instead of passing it as-is to the client for execution there. Therefore, client-side scripts put inside such a directory will not function as intended.

Unfortunately, this means that server-side and client-side scripts cannot co-exist in a single directory (except, perhaps, via the use of links, but I did not test that possibility).

Also, apparently for client-side scripts, a `VirtualHost`'s `DocumentRoot` becomes / for purposes of path specification in the HTML, though I believe (and did not test) that server-side scripts can be specified by a full path on the server's directory tree starting at the real root - or, again, possibly via a link but I didn't test that either.

**There's also a small lesson here about testing:** I'd have come across this solution sooner if I hadn't added the ScriptAlias directive, and so the lesson is to track what you change in an environment to get things working and sometimes you need to un-do a change for other changes to have proper effect. Lesson learned LONG-ago, re-learned today! Experience is recognizing a mistake when you make it again!